# Сложение массивов на php после запроса sql

Tags: php, sql, массивы

Идея, которую пытаюсь реализовать: для выбранных строк в таблице определить все столбцы, в которых есть данные, и получить (собрать) строку (массив), которая будет показывать наличие в столбцах элементов выбранных строк. Т.е. если есть 4 столбца, и первая строка содержит [1 0 1 0], вторая [0 1 1 0], то получить [1 1 1 0]. И потом записывать в другую таблицу данные в соответствии с полученной строкой.
Для этого делаю следующее. После запроса на SQL получаю ассоциативный массив. Далее разбиваю его на строки, которые записываю в новые массивы, и убираю первые 6 элементов. Далее необходимо суммировать поэлементно массивы и получить один массив. Как я понял, функции merge, diff на php не пойдут - куда копать? Или подход неверен в принципе? )
Запрос SQL:

```
$query_models="SELECT * FROM `model` WHERE des = '$des' AND gender = '$gender'";
```

Обработка результата:

```
if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_models)) {
$types = array();
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $types[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
}
$types1 = array();
$types2 = array();
$types1 = $types["0"];
$types2 = $types["1"];
$types1 = array_slice($types1,6);
$types2 = array_slice($types2,6);
$in = array($types1[0] + $types2[0], $types1[1] + $types2[1]);
print_r ($in);
```

Comment: *столбцы NOT NULL* Это что за зверь такой? В Вашем понимании...

Comment: Уточнил свою задачу) т.е. где есть данные

Comment: В такой постановке вопрос трудно понять, три раза перечитывал. Переформулируйте. Как вариант, напишите в таком формате: такие данные на входе, а нужно получить такие данные на выходе. Как я понял, нужно найти все пустые и не пустые колонки? Тогда это делается SQL-запросом и не нужно ничего фильтровать на PHP.

Comment: *определить все столбцы, в которых есть данные* В которых есть хотя бы одна запись с NOT NULL значением, или в которых нет ни одной записи с NULL значением? *если есть 4 столбца, и первая строка содержит [1 0 1 0], вторая [0 1 1 0], то получить [1 1 1 0]* Ну это тривиальный COUNT().

Comment: *Или подход неверен в принципе?* Однозначно. ВСЕ преобразования-вычисления сделает MySQL, причём сделает это он гораздо эффективнее, чем твоя не получающаяся программа.